# Cannot locate ABD.exe file for Emulator

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, adb

I believe the issue with my emulator is it is not finding my adb, and when I try to find it by running

```
which adb
```

I get `/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb`

The unfortunate thing is, the emulator wants a file from my finder, not just a route. When I search my finder, my `$USER` directory HAS no `Library` directory inside of it. I also checked my `Macintosh/Library` directory, but inside of there, there is no `Android` subdirectory.
Where can I find this? I have no idea where to find this, and evidently my emulator does not either

Comment: Did you add `$USER`? What's the output of `type adb` ?

Comment: that returns `adb is an alias for /Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb`

Comment: try `unalias adb` first